# Securing Wordpress on Apache

Tags: apache, wordpress, ubuntu, permissions, file-permissions

I've just set up a Wordpress blog on Slicehost using Ubuntu Jaunty and Apache.
I would like to have a clear overview how to fully secure it. I've read plenty articles on the net but none answers my questions:

- do I need to create a special
  user/user group for running
  wordpress?
- if yes how I configure    Apache,
  sftp and wordpress files to    work
  seamlessly together.

Currently I'm using a superuser to manage my VPS. I would like to have another user who manages only Wordpress.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Better suited for SuperUser...

Answer (score 1):

You're better off asking on SuperUser, where your question already has some answers: https://serverfault.com/search?q=apache+wordpress

Comment: I'v read all of them but no complete answer ... I've found a link which looks complete: http://joelmarcey.com/2008/08/15/installing-a-lamp-server-with-wordpress-on-slicehost-and-maybe-elsewhere/